# Convert String With Time in it to int

Tags: flutter, dart

I get the time of production into a String like time = "16:08". Format:"MM:SS", I need to convert it to int GETTING the seconds to add time on it and let it keep going.

Comment: ```parseFloat( "16:08".replace(":","."))```

Comment: But how can I get the seconds of 16 minutes?

Comment: you want to convert mins in seconds?

Comment: I have a String that gets the time from API, I need to convert it to seconds because I want to add more seconds while the product is still not finished.

Comment: I have an updated the answer, do check out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following steps:

```
String time = "16:08";
String myHour = time.substring(0, 2); // parse your string
String myMin = time.substring(2, 4); // parse your string

TimeOfDay thisTime = TimeOfDay(hour: int.parse(myHour), minute: int.parse(myMin)); // convert to TimeOfDay

TimeOfDay newTime = thisTime.replacing(hour: thisTime.hour - 2, minute: thisTime.minute + 2); // replace hour and minute
```

**EDIT:**

Ok, you can use the `Duration` class like this:

```
String time = "16:08";
String myMin = time.substring(0, 2);
String mySec = time.substring(2, 4);

Duration duration = Duration(minutes: int.parse(myMin) + 2, seconds: int.parse(mySec));
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that it's MM:SS, is there any way to convert it to that instead of HH:MM?

Comment: I instead would split on `:` in case the number of digits for the minutes isn't exactly 2.

Comment: It will add 2 minutes to the given duration. @some user

Comment: The user wanted in his own question.

 > add time on it